# how to define template function that takes two iterators in c++?

Tags: c++, function, templates, iterator, template-function

I would like to define a template function that takes two iterators, one being begin() and another being end(). How can this be achieved in c++?

So far, I can think of the following:

```cpp
template <class Iterator>
typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type func( Iterator begin, Iterator end ) {

}
```

Is this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the standard library tends to work (at least taking `<algorithm>` as an example) is to allow type resolution to happen later.  So you would instead use:

```
template <class InputIt, class T>
T func( InputIt begin, InputIt end )
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm just confused with this example of `class InputIt, class T`. What's class InputIT and class T? I read the same thing somewhere else and it confused me.

Comment: `InputIt` is the type used for the input iterators, and `T` is the type being returned. Iterators do not have to be actual `iterator` classes, they just need to support the `++`, `--`, and `*` operators. Raw pointers, for example, are valid iterators. So don't restrict your function to just `iterator` classes. If you are implementing a searching/modifying function, it would be better to return `InputIt` instead of `T` and let the caller decide what to do with the value of the returned iterator, if anything: `template <class InputIt> InputIt func( InputIt begin, InputIt end ) { ... }`